# How to execute command on urxvt startup

Tags: linux, terminal, bashrc, urxvt

Urxvt doesn't support using an I bar as the cursor. One of the ways i've found to get around this is to send the command `echo -n -e "\033[6 q"`.

This works as long as I send the command every time I open urxvt, which i'd rather not have to do.

I've tried to get urxvt to execute this on startup, with various degrees of success.

I tried to use `.bashrc`, with an `exec echo -n -e "\033[6 q"`. This didnt have any effect.

I use i3, so next i tried setting the keysym for urxvt to start with the command as well as using the `-hold` argument, but all that happened was that I was unable to use the terminal, as it was held.

The only thing i was able to do that had some success was to set a keysym in `.Xresources`:

`URxvt.keysym.C-Escape: command: \033[6 q`

This did work, but means that i have to press Ctrl-Escape everytime I start the terminal.

What i'd like to know is if there is any way to somehow run this command whenever i start urxvt, while still allowing me to actually use the terminal?

Comment: Why were you using `exec echo . . .` in your `.bashrc`?  Without seeing the whole thing it's hard to say for sure, but that doesn't feel right

Comment: yeah. I was trying anything and everything. I was pretty sure it would do nothing, but i figured it was worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put that into your `.bashrc` file, it would be improved a little:

- you should ensure that the string is directed to the *terminal*
- also, the shell should be interactive (in case some script source `.bashrc`)
- `echo` with the `-e` option has portability problems.  Use `printf`.

Putting those together, and writing to the standard error (because it's not buffered):

```
[ -n "PS1" ] && [ -t 2 ] && printf '\033[6 q' >&2
```

urxvt implements the `DECSCUSR` control sequence documented in [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html):

```
CSI Ps SP q
          Set cursor style (DECSCUSR, VT520).
            Ps = 0  -> blinking block.
            Ps = 1  -> blinking block (default).
            Ps = 2  -> steady block.
            Ps = 3  -> blinking underline.
            Ps = 4  -> steady underline.
            Ps = 5  -> blinking bar (xterm).
            Ps = 6  -> steady bar (xterm).
```

Note that codes 5 and 6 are xterm features.

This control sequence is not mentioned in the online manual page [urxvt(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/urxvt), but is noted in the [changelog entry](https://github.com/exg/rxvt-unicode/blob/master/Changes#L104):

```
9.19 Sun Oct 27 17:16:07 CET 2013
...
        - add support for the set cursor style (DECSCUSR) control
          function.
```

also the source code shows this (see [`set_cursor_style`](https://github.com/exg/rxvt-unicode/blob/master/src/command.C#L4034)), and the [source for the manual page](https://github.com/exg/rxvt-unicode/blob/master/doc/rxvt.7.man.in#L1901) shows the feature.  That was [updated in 2014 for codes 5 and 6](https://github.com/exg/rxvt-unicode/commit/97660c3e0040c1acf7b5479336cc3a8cf59fc7f0).

Further reading:

- [6.3.2 Is this Shell Interactive?](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f) (Bash reference manual)
- [6.4 Bash Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) (Bash reference manual)

Comment: Also you should check your terminal type. If you're using just rxvt and its variants, `[ "${TERM:0:4}" = rxvt ] && ...` should do the trick, otherwise you probably want to go with `case "$TERM" in; rxvt*) ...;; xterm*) ...;; esac` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -en "\x1b[\x35 q" # changes to blinking vertical bar
echo -en "\x1b[\x36 q" # changes to steady vertical bar
```

Those are the two relevant escape codes you need to put in your .bashrc to change it. Take everything else you've tried out first. And of course choose between steady or blinking, and comment out the other in case you want it later.

EDIT: To be more informative, I'm not sure if I can link anything, or where you got those codes, but I tested these in urxvt in my .bashrc and it's what I already used in xterm and they work, I can use all cursor shapes, if you need all the rest lemme know.

Answer (score 0):

If someone - like me, was searching for an answer to the question, not the specific problem of the guy who asked, the answer is:
`urxvt [your other options - e.g. fancy colors...] -hold -e <your command>`
If you omit `-hold` the terminal gets closed when the command is done.
example:
`urxvt -fg white -bg black -tr -sh 40 -fade 40 -sl 500 -cr yellow -e calc`
starts an urxvt with a calculator (a nice precision one on gentoo) and closes it when I close the calculator. I use this with an hot key.
other example:
`urxvt -fg white -bg black -tr -sh 40 -fade 40 -sl 500 -cr yellow -hold -e echo -e Hello you greatest hacker\n`
would greet a narcissistic user while open the terminal window and stays open. I don't use the latter example.